# If query - still executes?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, execute

I'm new to PHP and got stuck on how a query still can execute even though it is in an if-statement.

Example/

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO db_name (table1, table2)<br>
VALUES ('value1', 'value2')";

if (!mysql_query($sql) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
Echo 'Created';
```

There, that if statement it executes the query just fine, but how? It's an if-statement. It should just check values, not execute conditions.

Comment: Works as designed - to check the value it needs to execute the query, doesn't it?

Comment: So it executes everyting in the function until it reaches the return result, and then that is what the if-statement compares with. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you're correct in your assumption.

Answer (score 4):

What this piece of code essentially can be read as:

1. execute mysql_query() with $sql as its parameter
2. get its return value
3. check return value against `true`/`false`
4. if `false` - die
5. if `true` - print `Created`.

Comment: Thank you! So it executes already in the if-statement. Does this apply to all if statements? Is it because mysql_query() is a function?

Comment: Yes, to compare two conditionals they must be evaluated. What are you trying to achieve with that piece of code?

Comment: Not much, just educational. Every new command is an aha-experience right now ;) Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

If I've interpreted your question correctly, the code will execute the query and check the return value, which will then be evaluated in the if statement.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it because mysql_query() is a function?

Answer (score 0):

The if statement is about evaluating an expression, thus if you have a function that returns something you can do this kind of if statement.

In this case `mysql_query()` is a function that returns a Boolean value true or false indicating if the query was executed ok or not.

Here the if statement is evaluating `!mysql_query($sql)` will evaluate to true if it failed, false if it succeeded. And thus display an error if it failed.